# How to convert ImageSource scanned using NTwain to pdf file?

Tags: wpf

i have tried :
  File.WriteAllBytes("my.pdf",byts);

It saves file and i can open using browser but with Pdf Reader (Any), it throws error (Send as email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded ).

I am searching something opensource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long day search , i found alternative as PdfSharp. i am pasting my code here for converting scanned bitmapsource to pdf file.

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
PdfPage page = doc.AddPage();
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
XImage image = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(img);// System.Drawing.Image
gfx.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, 612, 792);
doc.Save("my1.pdf");
```